# Not able to access session data inside web.php

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to use session variable in my web.php file. As I want to create dynamic route according to current_index from session. And current_index is changed as per different login.

```
$index = Session::get('current_index');


Route::prefix($index)->group(function () {
            Route::get('index', [SystemConfigController::class, 'index'])->name('systemConfig.index');
            Route::post('list', [SystemConfigController::class, 'index'])->name('systemConfig.list');
            Route::post('testmail', [SystemConfigController::class, 'testMail'])->name('systemConfig.testmail');
            Route::post('edittable', [SystemConfigController::class, 'editTable'])->name('systemConfig.edittable');
        });
```

Can you please help me to figure out this issue?

middlewareGroups from kernel.php file :

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Edited below :

I have scenario like this. I have to create dynamic route like below:

```
$index = Session::get('current_index');
```

If $index is 0 then my route list is like below :

```
Route::prefix(0)->group(function () {
    Route::get('index', [SystemConfigController::class, 'index'])->name('systemConfig.index');
    Route::post('list', [SystemConfigController::class, 'index'])->name('systemConfig.list');
    Route::post('testmail', [SystemConfigController::class, 'testMail'])->name('systemConfig.testmail');
    Route::post('edittable', [SystemConfigController::class, 'editTable'])->name('systemConfig.edittable');
});
```

If $index is 1 then my route list is like below :

```
Route::prefix(1)->group(function () {
    Route::get('index', [SystemConfigController::class, 'index'])->name('systemConfig.index');
    Route::post('list', [SystemConfigController::class, 'index'])->name('systemConfig.list');
    Route::post('testmail', [SystemConfigController::class, 'testMail'])->name('systemConfig.testmail');
    Route::post('edittable', [SystemConfigController::class, 'editTable'])->name('systemConfig.edittable');
});
```

Comment: RouteServiceProvider are booted before the StartSession middleware, so you cannot access session in route files. Use middleware to check instead

Comment: create middleware and use session

Answer (score 1):

Load session before initiating routes

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, 
    ],
];
```

---

```
Route::prefix($index)
    ->middleware('web')
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('index', [SystemConfigController::class, 'index'])->name('systemConfig.index');
        Route::post('list', [SystemConfigController::class, 'index'])->name('systemConfig.list');
        Route::post('testmail', [SystemConfigController::class, 'testMail'])->name('systemConfig.testmail');
        Route::post('edittable', [SystemConfigController::class, 'editTable'])->name('systemConfig.edittable');
    });
```

Comment: Where should I replace Startsession middleware. I edit my question. Can you please check?

Comment: @NishaPatel `app/Http/Kernel.php` and use `Route::prefix($index)
    ->middleware('web')
    ->group(function () {)` alter your group as well

Comment: Thank you @Abdulla Nilam, I have tried above answer. But its not working. Session::get('current_index') is not get in web.php file. I have edited my question again. Can you please check?

Comment: @NishaPatel add `->middleware('web') ` before prefix

Comment: stll not working by above solution.

Answer (score 1):

RouteServiceProvider are booted before the StartSession middleware, so you cannot access session in route files. Use middleware to check instead

```
Route::middleware('session.has.index')->prefix($index)->group(function () {
   Route::get('index', [SystemConfigController::class, 'index'])->name('systemConfig.index');
   Route::post('list', [SystemConfigController::class, 'index'])->name('systemConfig.list');
   Route::post('testmail', [SystemConfigController::class, 'testMail'])->name('systemConfig.testmail');
   Route::post('edittable', [SystemConfigController::class, 'editTable'])->name('systemConfig.edittable');
});
```

create middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware SessionHasIndex
```

Update middlewares to check the session, if it does not have corresponding session, abort the request:

**app/Http/Middleware/SessionHasIndex.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) 
{ 
    $request->route()->prefix(Session::get('index')); 
    return $next($request); 
}
```

Install Middlewares, so routing can use the middlewares

**app/Http/Kernel.php**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        'session.has.index' => , \App\Http\Middleware\SessionHasIndex::class       
        ...
    ],
```